# Facebook Referral URL decode

Tags: facebook, api, url

Sometimes I get burst of visitors from Facebook, which I am curious to know where exactly on Facebook if the page is public, of course!

Is there a way to decode and track back Facebook referral URL to actual page in the Facebook?

URL format is the following:
http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F&h=iAQDjUC4AQHjQeIXcOi8z9jamgyDk8vpuylpdaRT3aHu6Q&s=1

From mobile it is shorter:
http://m.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F&h=BAQFX067m&s=1

Where `domain.com` is my website for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the URL manually using `substr` and then apply `decodeURIComponent`:

```js
function extractFacebookUrl(u) {
    u = u.substr(u.indexOf('l.php?u=') + 8); // remove before ?u=
    u = u.substr(0, u.indexOf('&')); // remove after &

    return decodeURIComponent(u);
}

var link = "http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F&h=iAQDjUC4AQHjQeIXcOi8z9jamgyDk8vpuylpdaRT3aHu6Q&s=1";
var linkMobile = "http://m.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F&h=BAQFX067m&s=1";

document.body.innerHTML = extractFacebookUrl(link) + "<br/>" + extractFacebookUrl(linkMobile);
```